# calculate the surface area of the part of a cylinder $ x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1 $ that is inside the sphere $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4 $.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

calculate the surface area of the part of a cylinder $ x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1 $ that is inside the sphere
$  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4 $.

my trial :

The Domain of integration on the YZ plane is :

solving :

**(*)** $  x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1 $

$ x^2 + (y)^2 + z^2 \leq 4 $

We get : $ 0 \leq z \leq \sqrt{4-2y}$
and   $ -2 \leq y \leq 2 $

$||\nabla{Cylinder(x,y,z)}|| = ||(2x,2(y-1),0)|| = 2 ~$ **see(*)**

S = $2~\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-2y}}~~2~dydz$ ( by symmetry *2)

I also tried solving by parmetrization and i didn't get the same answer i really need HELP is this way alright ? or is there something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma : [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2, \gamma(t) = (\cos t, 1+\sin t)$ be the parameterization of the circle $x^2+(y-1)^2 = 1$ in the $xy$-plane.

The height of the cylinder over a point $(x,y)$ on this circle is given by $z = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ so the area is

$$A = 2\int_\gamma z\,d\gamma = 2\int_\gamma \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}\,d\gamma = 2\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{4-\cos^2t -(1+\sin t)^2}\,dt = 2\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2(1-\sin t)}\,dt$$

We can solve this integral by noting that $1-\sin t = \left(\sin\frac{t}2 - \cos\frac{t}2\right)^2$ so we get
$$A = 16$$

Is this result what you are getting?

Comment: exactly ! i did get this and with the same steps

Comment: what is wrong with this answer i wrote up there

Comment: i really cant find anything wrong with it

Comment: wait i think i got the mistake the surface is $z(x,y)$ and i wrote something far beyond right . thanks for helping me !!!

Comment: @Mather Your domain of integration is also off, I believe it should be $y \in [0,2], z \in [0,\sqrt{4-y^2}]$. How did you get $\sqrt{4-2y}$?

Comment: $ x^2 + y^2 = 2y $  ~~ so ~~ $2y + z^2  \leq 4 $

Comment: @i707107 Intuitively, the area element $dA$ of the cylinder is the product of the infinitesimal line element $d\gamma$ on the circle and the height of the cylinder over that line element, which is $z = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$. Hence $$dA = \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}\, d\gamma$$
Integrating this over $\gamma$ yields the surface area.

Comment: did you see  why the domain is that ? @mechanodroid

Comment: I understand now. I misread the problem as "part of cylinder" as "part of sphere"

Comment: @Mather I don't get it. First notice that $y \in [0,2]$. Then the condition $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4$ should be the bound for $z$ since the cylinder doesn't depend on $z$. Since we are in the $yz$-plane, it is $x = 0$ so $y^2+z^2 = 4$ and from here $0 \le z \le \sqrt{4-y^2}$.

Comment: Now parameterize the cylinder over this domain by $$\phi(y,z) = \left(\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2},y,z\right)$$
and calculate the surface element, which I think is $\frac{dy\,dz}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}$.